# Value not properly routing after multiple routes added to a single route

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am trying crud in node mongoose. I got stuck when I started adding multiple routes to a single route. When I first added add function to only one page it was working perfectly good. But as started adding add function to the same router now it's not working. Can anyone please help?

route.js

```
//category

router.get('/category',async (req,res,next) => {
  const categoryPages = await Category . find();
  res.render('category' , {
      categoryPages
  });

});

router.post('/addCategory', async (req,res,next) => { 
  const categoryPages = new Category({
      category : req.body.category ,
      status : req.body.status
  });
  await categoryPages.save();
  console.log('received');
  res.redirect('/category');
});

//story

router.get('/Story',async (req,res) => {try {
  var Stories = await Story.find();
  res.render('Story' , {
      Stories
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

});


router.post('/addStory', async (req,res) => {try{
  var successStories = new Story({
      Story : req.body.Story ,
      StoryStatus : req.body.StoryStatus
  });
  await Stories.save();
  console.log('received');
  res.redirect('/Story');
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

});


//patners
router.get('/partners',async (req,res) => {try {
  const partners = await Partners.find();
  res.render('partners' , {
      partners
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

});


router.post('/addpartners', async (req,res) => {try{
  const partners = new Partners({
      partnersList : req.body.partnersList ,
      partnerStatus : req.body.partnerStatus
  });
  await partners.save();
  console.log('received');
  res.redirect('/partners');
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

});
```

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    category: {
        type:String
    },
    status: {
        type:String
    }

})
const SuccessStorySchema = new Schema({
    Story: {
        type:String
    },
    StoryStatus: {
        type:String
    }
})


const PartnerSchema = new Schema({
    partnersList: {
        type:String
    },
    partnerStatus: {
        type:String
    }
})


module.exports =  mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
module.exports =  mongoose.model('SuccessStory',SuccessStorySchema);
module.exports =  mongoose.model('Partners',PartnerSchema);
```

Story.ejs

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < successStories. length; i++) { %>     
<tr>
    <td><%= i+1 %></td>
    <td><%= successStories[i].Story %></td>
    <td><%= successStories[i].StoryStatus %></td>
</tr>
<%  } %>
```

Partners.ejs

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < partners. length; i++) { %>           
   <tr>
     <td><%= i+1 %></td>
     <td><%= partners[i].partnersList %></td>
     <td><%= partners[i].partnerStatus %></td>
   </tr>
<%  } %>
```

Category.ejs

```
<% for(var i = 0; i <categoryPages. length; i++) { %>   
<tr>
 <td><%= i+1 %></td>
 <td><%= categoryPages[i].category %></td>
 <td><%= categoryPages[i].status %></td>
</tr>
<%  } %>
```

Getting result
[image]

In cmd I get

[image]

In mongoose, no record is added and no schema is shown

Comment: Anyone, please help??

Comment: where is mongoose connection with node js?

Comment: it's in index.js page

Comment: You need to check first the route you are calling is working or not(by logging console)?
if routes are ok the then you need to check the connection with your node js application is Ok or not? then check mongoose schema is OK or not?
then check data is ok according to mongoose schema?
if you follow these steps you will definitely find where is the issue?

Comment: routes and connections are working

Comment: the issue is that when I add both routes, it's not working, No record is shown only object id is stored. Value is not inserted.

Comment: the only one-way community can help you is you share repo with us.